# Loop over rows in worksheet and merge cells in Python

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlwings

I would like to loop over my DataFrame worksheet and merge the cells in every 2 rows within one column. For example my DataFrame looks like this:

[image: Current Dataframe]

However, the end goal is for it to look like this:

[image: Dataframe with merged cells]

I typically use xlwings for excel related work in Python but I am not sure if it's the most useful package for this task.

I see it is possible to merge cells based on a static range but unsure how to implement this in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First, replace your empty cells with NaNs:

```
import numpy as np
df.Client = df.Client[df.Client.str.strip() != '']
```

Then Use ffill() to fill empty cells with previous row value:

```
df.Client=df.Client.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Merge row cells of same value into one:

```
df=df.set_index(['Client','Staff Name'])
```

Result:

[image]